# Real time digital signal processing (dsp) library

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm looking to implement some real-time digital signal processing noise reduction techniques for audio and acceleration signals.  Does anyone know if there are any DSP libraries with ROS wrappers already?  If not does anyone have experience with a library that they can recommend?

At a minimum I need fourier transform and inverse fourier transform support (which I know I can get from http://www.fftw.org/, but STFT/iSTFT and wavelet transform capabilities would be awesome.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10216/real-time-digital-signal-processing-(dsp)-library/) by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've not seen any ROS digital signal processing wrappers, but there may be some.

A ROS wrapper for FFTW seems useful and not too difficult.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-08-29**:
For a mature, widely-available library like FFTW, a  reference to the system version is probably better than creating a ROS package.